# Python: dates overlap with non dates xtickslabel while plotting dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, date, matplotlib, timestamp

I have a datframe that looks like the following

```
df
            hourloc
date    
2020-03-01  5.205604
2020-03-02  6.017208
2020-03-03  6.306644
2020-03-04  6.229173
2020-03-05  6.195318
2020-03-06  6.227044
2020-03-07  5.773543
2020-03-08  5.240742
2020-03-09  5.822339
2020-03-10  6.206322
2020-03-11  6.165573
2020-03-12  6.176903
2020-03-13  6.144732
2020-03-14  5.696014
2020-03-15  5.383493
2020-03-16  5.561784
2020-03-17  6.046331
2020-03-18  6.253435
2020-03-19  6.114415
2020-03-20  6.395085
2020-03-21  5.914373
2020-03-22  5.434104
2020-03-23  6.011175
2020-03-24  6.231768
2020-03-25  6.198261
2020-03-26  6.324300
2020-03-27  6.428962
```

that I am trying to plot

```
f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
df.plot(x='date', y = 'hourloc', ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() 
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Why do the dates overlap with "normal" xtickslabel?

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? I am using matplotlib 3.1.2 and when I run your code, only the dates show up as I would expect.